# Cut/paste cells to a new sheet with certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need to move cells A-M in a given row to another sheet based on a certain criteria. Right now I am using a code that moves the entire row (see below). How can I edit this in order to only take the values from A-M? I'd appreciate any insight, as I'm very new to this. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fr33M4cro()

Dim sh33tName As String
Dim custNameColumn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim stRow As Long
Dim customer As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetExist As Boolean
Dim sh As Worksheet

sh33tName = "New Providers - FPPE"
custNameColumn = "H"
stRow = 7

Set sh = Sheets(sh33tName)

For i = sh.Range(custNameColumn & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To stRow Step -1
    customer = sh.Range(custNameColumn & i).Value
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If StrComp(ws.Name, customer, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sheetExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If sheetExist Then
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
    Else
        InsertSheet customer
        Set ws = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
    End If
    Reset sheetExist
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CopyRow(i As Long, ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByRef ws As Worksheet, custNameColumn As String)
Dim wsRow As Long
wsRow = ws.Range(custNameColumn & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


ws.Rows(wsRow).EntireRow.Value = sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub


Private Sub Reset(ByRef x As Boolean)
x = False
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSheet(shName As String)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = shName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CopyRow` function, do this instead:

```
' ws.Rows(wsRow).EntireRow.Value = sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
ws.Rows(wsRow).Resize(1,13).Value = sh.Rows(i).Resize(1,13).Value
```

Comment: The whole row is still being cut... any insight to what may be going on?

Comment: You didn't say anything about cutting (or not cutting) in your question, but you can use the same approach: `sh.Rows(i).Resize(1,13).Delete Shift:=xlUp`